# Manually fire event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating a list of input boxes in JQuery and have an event to notify me when they are checked.

```
$("#myDiv").on("change",  "input[type='checkbox']" , function(){
   if(this.checked){
     alert("HERE");
     //...
   }else{
    alert("THERE");
    //...
   }
});
```

When the page loads and all the checkboxes show - I can have this enter by checking/unchecking.  The problem is that I want a few of these to be checked initially depending on the results of my backend logic.  So I want to enter this function after the initial load.

I looked at `.trigger()` and `.click()` however, neither seem to do the trick.

Is there another avenue I could take to enter this callback?

Comment: I'm not sure what do answer. May you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: since you are attaching to the `change` event, have you tried `.change()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can create a named function instead of using an anonymous one and call it whenever you need.

```
var myFunction = function(){
   if(this.checked){
     alert("HERE");
     //...
   }else{
    alert("THERE");
    //...
   }
}

$("#myDiv").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", myFunction );

// triggering the function manually:
$("#myDiv input[type='checkbox']").each( myFunction );
```

Comment: in my $document.ready I now have your 
$("#myDiv").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", myFunction );

and that works whenever I check a box.

However, the $("#myDiv input[type='checkbox']").each( myFunction );
does not call said function.

Comment: You need to put it to $( document ).ready() as well. Otherwise the DOM hasn't loaded yet and the element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show checked on a checkbox, just set `checked` property to `checked`

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='checked' />
```

If you want to fire `change();` event,

```
$('<your_checkbox>').change();
```

or

```
$('<you_checkbox>').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is triggered when myDiv is changing, and you pass a list of checkbox. here 'this' is the mydiv. why not using:

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function(){// Now this is referring your checkbox});
```

Comment: Hmm, it would seem for me in firebug 'this' is refering to the whole document.  However, it's firing which is a step closer

Answer (score 0):

Define your function separately by name and then call it after the page has loaded for each item that has been checked off.

```
function onChange(this) {
    if(this.checked){
        alert("HERE");
        //...
    }else{
        alert("THERE");
        //...
    }
}
```

Your code that monitors checkbox changes would become:

```
$("#myDiv").on("change",  "input[type='checkbox']" , function() {
    onChange(this);
});
```

Since I don't know what the code looks like, I've written some code to print check boxes and define which ones are to be selected by default. It is PHP, but the concept should work for any server side language.

```
<select>
<?php
$items = array(
    'value1' => 'text1',
    'value2' => 'text2',
    'value3' => 'text3'
);

$selected = array(
    'value1' => true,
    'value3' => true
);

foreach ($items as $value => $text) {
    $selectedAttr = isset($selected[$value]) && $selected[$value]) ?
        " selected='selected'" : '';
    echo "<option value='$value'$selectedAttr>$text</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

You'll need to print javascript that runs the function that you want to have executed for each selected option. For the checkbox example that I used, the end result that you'd want is:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var defaultSelected = [ "[option name='value1']" , "[option name='value3']" ];

    for (var i=0; i < defaultSelected.length; i++) {
        $(defaultSelected[i]).each(onChange);
    }
});
```

You'll need to generate the javascript on the server side:

```
<?php

// $selected was defined in the previous code section

// Create selectors that will select each checkbox option
$selectors = array();
foreach ($selected as $s) {
    array_push($selectors, "[option name='$s']");
}

// Produces string: [ "[option name='value1']" , "[option name='value3']" ]
$jsSelectorArray = '[ "' . implode('" , "', $selectors) . '" ]';

echo "
$().ready(function() {
    var defaultSelected = $jsSelectorArray;

    for (var i=0; i < defaultSelected.length; i++) {
        $(defaultSelected[i]).each(function() {
            onChange(this);
        });
    }
});
";

?>
```